# Cpanel - I am trying to install pillow module on my python django web.. but is not installing

Tags: python, django, terminal, python-imaging-library, cpanel

**domain**: [www.snatchupjobs.com](http://www.snatchupjobs.com)
when I remove pillow modules lines from my website then my website run perfectly but when I do not remove the pillow lines from my website then my website stops working.. it shows an error "no module name pillow". actually, my application depends on this library. the flow of my website is that users can create a CV and also users can download it; on downloading processing time I used pillow module which will convert html to png then png to pdf file... so kindly help me to solve this code

here is the lines I am getting from cpanel terminal when I run this command pip install pillow..

---

[cpanel terminal error during the module installing time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDbb6.png)

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like a missing package, thus please make sure that you have installed the development tools packages first:

sudo yum group install "Development Tools"

and make sure that the compiler is available after that:

gcc --version

If the issue still persists, I would definitely recommend checking this further with your hosting provider. They should be able to help. If not, I recommend finding a managed vps/ds provider and moving there.